# How do I use select distinct with a join on another table in Oracle SQL?

Tags: sql, oracle, join, distinct

I'm fairly new to SQL and only have read access to the database that I'm using.  I'm trying to query the number of work orders (WO) in the table WRK that are in the state of PA (and yes it is labeled as state PA in the database, not pA or Pa).  I also need the date the work order was created, which comes from a different table, table STR in the column CREATED.  When I run the below code, I get duplicate work orders all with the same data, which ends up being 3 million+ records and takes some time to pull from the database.  I imagine Select Distinct is the way I need to go, but could be wrong.  I've tried searching on here and a couple other places for code that would do what I need to do, which is return only 1 work order instead of multiple duplicate records.  I also need the person who created the work order "WRK.PERSON", and this will always be the same person for any given work order. The join is throwing everything off, but I can't find a way around it.  Thank you in advance!

Code:

```
Select WRK.WO, WRK.PERSON, STR.CREATED
FROM WRK
JOIN STR on WRK.WO = STR.WO
WHERE WRK.STATE = 'PA'
```

Current results:

| WO | Person | Created |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 280 | W123 | 20220101 |
| 280 | W123 | 20220101 |
| 280 | W123 | 20220101 |
| 280 | W123 | 20220101 |
| 299 | E201 | 20200531 |
| 299 | E201 | 20200531 |
| 299 | E201 | 20200531 |
| 300 | R360 | 20221115 |
| 300 | R360 | 20221115 |
| 300 | R360 | 20221115 |

Desired results:

| WO | Person | Created |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 280 | W123 | 20220101 |
| 299 | E201 | 20200531 |
| 300 | R360 | 20221115 |

Thanks to Paul W - the below code works:

```
Select /*+ full(wrk) parallel(8) USE_HASH(wrk str) */
      WRK.WO, WRK.PERSON, STR.CREATED
FROM WRK
JOIN (SELECT /*+ NO_MERGE */
           wo,
           MAX(created) created
      FROM str
     GROUP BY wo) STR on WRK.WO = STR.WO
WHERE WRK.STATE = 'PA'
```

Comment: Try adding `Distinct`. Ie.`Select Distinct WRK.WO, WRK.PERSON, STR.CREATED...`.  Looks like it will achieve exactly what you want.

Comment: @AaronDietz I tried Select DISTINCT WRK.WO, WRK.PERSON, STR.CREATED to no avail.  I also tried
Select WRK.WO, WRK.PERSON, STR.CREATED
with a GROUP BY WRK.WO, WRK.PERSON, STR.CREATED which still produced dupe WO's

Comment: @smurfit -  Please provide some sample data for both tables. There are some duplicate rows somewhere. If there is just 1 row for every WO value in both tables your SQL would work as desired. Something is missing here...

Comment: Do you only want one "created" value from str ? If so, would you want just the latest one for the WO ?

Comment: @dr what sample data are you looking for.  I just did a simple list everything query of both tables for 280 and WRK has one entry and you are correct the dupes are in table STR

Comment: @PaulW yes one created value (the latest is ok) from STR would work

Comment: Then see my answer below. Let me know if it works for you.

Answer (score 1):

Will this work for you? Main thing is ensuring that you don't have a many-to-many join by reducing at least one side to uniqueness on the join column. I also threw in some hints you may want given the volume of data to help deal with the performance.

```
Select /*+ full(wrk) parallel(8) USE_HASH(wrk str) */
       WRK.WO, WRK.PERSON, STR.CREATED
FROM WRK
JOIN (SELECT /*+ NO_MERGE */
             wo,
             MAX(created) created
        FROM str
       GROUP BY wo) STR on WRK.WO = STR.WO
WHERE WRK.STATE = 'PA'
```

Comment: The above code worked. Thank you much for your quick response and help!

Answer (score 1):

```sql
WITH
    tbl_wrk AS 
        (
            Select 280 "WO", 'W123' "PERSON", 'PA' "STATE" From Dual Union All
            Select 299 "WO", 'E201' "PERSON", 'PA' "STATE" From Dual Union All
            Select 300 "WO", 'R360' "PERSON", 'PA' "STATE" From Dual Union All
      --
            Select 180 "WO", 'Q333' "PERSON", 'NY' "STATE" From Dual Union All
            Select 220 "WO", 'K123' "PERSON", 'NY' "STATE" From Dual 
        ),
    tbl_str AS
        (
            Select 280 "WO", '20220101' "CREATED" From Dual Union All
            Select 280 "WO", '20220101' "CREATED" From Dual Union All
            Select 280 "WO", '20220101' "CREATED" From Dual Union All
      --
            Select 299 "WO", '20200531' "CREATED" From Dual Union All
            Select 299 "WO", '20200531' "CREATED" From Dual Union All
            Select 299 "WO", '20200531' "CREATED" From Dual Union All
      --
            Select 300 "WO", '20221115' "CREATED" From Dual Union All
            Select 300 "WO", '20221115' "CREATED" From Dual Union All
            Select 300 "WO", '20221115' "CREATED" From Dual Union All
      --
            Select 180 "WO", '20190318' "CREATED" From Dual Union All
            Select 220 "WO", '20210109' "CREATED" From Dual 
        )
SELECT        w.WO, w.PERSON, Max(CREATED) "CREATED"
FROM          tbl_wrk w
INNER JOIN    tbl_str s ON(s.WO = w.WO)
WHERE         w.STATE = 'PA'
GROUP BY      w.WO, w.PERSON
ORDER BY      w.WO

        WO PERSON CREATED
---------- ------ --------
       280 W123   20220101 
       299 E201   20200531 
       300 R360   20221115
```